# Show numbers with decimal places only when they are not followed in zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

**Table:**

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (p1 decimal(9,2), p2 decimal(9,2))
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES (10.5,9),(2,4),(10.5,9.5),(40,90),(10,9.56)
```

**Query:**

```
select IIF(FLOOR(p1) <> CEILING(p1) OR FLOOR(p2) <> CEILING(p2),CAST(p1 AS VARCHAR)+'-'+CAST(p2 AS VARCHAR), CAST( CAST(p1 AS int) as varchar)+'-'+cast( CAST(p2 AS int) as varchar)) AS Data from @tab
```

**Output:**

[image]

I want to show in decimal only if decimal value is not zero or more than zero. My first data 10.5 and 9, I want to show it as 10.50-9, but it is showing as 10.50-9.00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the formatting by column before concatenating them. Using your given  code, I modified it to this

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (p1 decimal(9,2), p2 decimal(9,2))
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES (10.5,9),(2,4),(10.5,9.5),(40,90),(10,9.56)

SELECT IIF(FLOOR(p1)<> CEILING(p1),CAST(p1 AS VARCHAR),CAST( CAST(p1 AS int) as varchar)) +'-'+ 
IIF(FLOOR(p2)<> CEILING(p2),CAST(p2 AS VARCHAR),CAST( CAST(p2 AS int) as varchar)) as Data1 FROM @tab;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c5f2cfbfed2869881df0d823333f015a)

Answer (score 1):

So far you have one condition (`IIF`) on the two columns combined. You want separate conditions instead:

```
select
  case when floor(p1) <> ceiling(p1) then 
    cast(p1 as varchar)
  else
    cast(cast(p1 as int) as varchar)
  end +
  '-' +
  case when floor(p2) <> ceiling(p2) then
    cast(p2 as varchar)
  else
    cast(cast(p2 as int) as varchar)
  end as data
from @tab;
```

(I've replaced TSQL's proprietary `IIF` with standard SQL's `CASE WHEN` here, but you can also use `IIF` of course.)

More typically you would use `STR` to explicitely convert a number to a string with a desired number of decimals:

```
case when floor(p1) <> ceiling(p1) then 
  str(p1, 10, 2)
else
  str(p1, 10, 0)
end
```

STR ( float_expression [ , length [ , decimal ] ] )